# Does the MySQL "set" field type work in ActiveRecord/Ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

Has anyone use the sql 'set' mysql field type in ActiveRecord / Ruby? suggestions, feedback, cavetats

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/) implies that it is converted to a `String` (which is presumably comma-separated).

Comment: @voondo: It works for me: http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/